# .aar integration is having some strange behaviour on CN1 buildserver side

Tags: build, codenameone, aar

In my CN1 project I am adding one .aar file that is having a library with .so file.

It was properly working upto last friday 19 Feb 2016. But now today on Monday 22nd Feb without changing anything I sent a build and it came with lesser sized APK.

Then I compared friday's apk and today's apk and I found that .so files are missing in newer apk that was inherited from .aar to apk's libs directory.
[image]
Then I tried to build another project and integrated .aar from scratch but in that project also there was no .so files in lib.

I am wondering that anything is changed on Codename One build server side !?

Thanks.

Comment: just another guess during testing : I added another separate .aar library with size of 3 MB and surprisingly the size of apk was same as it was with only 1 .aar library. So I guess its not considering .aar file at all. I might be wrong, but this is what I found after adding 3MB file and didnt get any change in build apk generated on server.

Comment: adding aar works fine for me, try to do build with sources and open the project in android studio to figure out what went wrong

Comment: @Chen I tried to do build with source and the source package shows me .aar in libs directory. I am able to import that source into android studio but not able to run it. Its just showing me 're-download dependency and sync' error and when I click on this it process for few mins and ends.
But it was working upto friday, I mean those .so files were added from .aar to build apk's libs directory and now all of a sudden it stops without changing anythin.
Any other suggestion please.

Comment: @Chen is it possibly that I am having two different .aar files and because of that its ignoring 2nd .aar project library !? Also again even if I tried to add 2nd library with 3MB or 8MB its completely ignored by build server..I mean no .so files are imported into newer apk from 2ns .aar. It only adds .so files from first .arr file.

Comment: FYI : For testing, I created new sample project in Android Studio and tried to add my .aar file and it did generate proper apk with those .so files from aar to apk's lib\armeabi\ directory.

Comment: can you create such test project and submit an issue? to the git issue tracker.